# c# DataTable Trials

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have an ASP.NET DataTable which I am populating from another set of ASP:TextBox Fields to Store to then Bulk Insert into a Database when I click the add button I get System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox added to the DataTable Instead of the Data I have Entered in the fields can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

The Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDataTable._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <legend>Add New Order
    <div>
    <fieldset style="height:200px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTips" runat="server" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Red" Width="100%" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            Width="100%" CellPadding="4" EmptyDataText="There is no any data." 
            ForeColor="#333333" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountRef" HeaderText="Account #" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvRef" HeaderText="Invoice Ref" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustOrderNo" HeaderText="Order Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitAmount" HeaderText="Unit Amount" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Line Total" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TakenBy" HeaderText="Taken By" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow EnableTheming="true" BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White">
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Account Ref:</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Invoice Ref</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Customer Order #</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Product</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Qty</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Unit Amount</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Value</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Taken By</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableRow ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#F7F6F3">
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountRef" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceRef" runat="server"></asp:TextBox ></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtCustOrderNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtTakenBy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table> 
    </fieldset>
    </div>
  </legend>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestDataTable
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        internal DataTable myDt = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                myDt = new DataTable();
                myDt = CreateDataTable();
                Session["myDatatable"] = myDt;

                this.GridView1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["myDatatable"]).DefaultView;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtAccountRef.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                this.lblTips.Text = "You must have an Account Number.";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                AddDataToTable (
                    this.txtAccountRef.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtInvoiceRef.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtCustOrderNo.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtProduct.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtQty.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtUnitAmount.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtValue.Text.Trim(),
                    this.txtTakenBy.Text.Trim(),
                    (DataTable)Session["myDatatable"]
                );


                this.GridView1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["myDatatable"]).DefaultView;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();

                this.txtAccountRef.Text = "";
                this.txtInvoiceRef.Text = "";
                this.txtCustOrderNo.Text = "";
                this.txtProduct.Text = "";
                this.txtQty.Text = "";
                this.txtUnitAmount.Text = "";
                this.txtValue.Text = "";
                this.txtTakenBy.Text = "";
                this.lblTips.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void AddDataToTable(string AccountRef, string InvRef, string CustOrderNo, string Product, string Qty, string UnitAmount, string Value, string TakenBy, DataTable myTable)
        {
            DataRow row;

            row = myTable.NewRow();

            row["id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            row["AccountRef"] = txtAccountRef;
            row["InvRef"] = txtInvoiceRef;
            row["CustOrderNo"] = txtCustOrderNo;
            row["Product"] = txtProduct;
            row["Qty"] = txtQty;
            row["UnitAmount"] = txtUnitAmount;
            row["Value"] = txtValue;
            row["TakenBy"] = txtTakenBy;


            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        private DataTable CreateDataTable()
        {
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

            DataColumn myDataColumn;

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "id";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "AccountRef";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "InvRef";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "CustOrderNo";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Product";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Qty";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "UnitAmount";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Value";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
            myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "TakenBy";
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

            return myDataTable;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! 
Justin

Comment: Still looking into your problem, but as an aside I see you're keeping your datatable in the session.  It probably a lot more peformant to just send the row directly to the database right away ever time a user clicks add, rather than bulk-inserting.  The memory consumption keeping a table like that in every session can come back to bite you.

Comment: Justin, where did you get this code? I don't want to put you down - I want to help you, but there are so many things that are wrong with this piece of code that I don't know where to begin.

Comment: @MikeEast I am a newbie to this c# thingy ;) I got it from http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/data-table-csharp.aspx is there a better way?

Comment: The article you link to is a bit outdated in the sense that it is using `DataTable` in the first place, but its implementation is also fundamentally wrong. Refer to more updated tutorials at http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `.Text` property; use it to assign text of your control:

```
row["AccountRef"] = txtAccountRef.Text;
        row["InvRef"] = txtInvoiceRef.Text;
        row["CustOrderNo"] = txtCustOrderNo.Text;
        row["Product"] = txtProduct.Text;
        row["Qty"] = txtQty.Text;
        row["UnitAmount"] = txtUnitAmount.Text;
        row["Value"] = txtValue.Text;
        row["TakenBy"] = txtTakenBy.Text;
```

Comment: Shouldn't he be assigning the values that were passed into the method instead??

Comment: @muhammad-akhtar can you tell me how to do this for a DropDown list option i.e. would it be 'row["Product"] = txtProduct.Value;' or maybe something else?

Comment: if you have dropdown for your product then it will be   'row["Product"] = ProductDropdownID.SelectedValue;'

Comment: thanks hoever when I try that I get the following 'txtProduct' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `AddDataToTable()` method.  You define the parameters for that function like this:

> string AccountRef

but then assign values to a row like this:

> row["AccountRef"] = txtAccountRef;

See the difference?  The second excerpt is using the control on your page, rather than parameter you passed in.  You should change it to look like this:

> row["AccountRef"] = AccountRef;